# Array.filter not return exactly properties of object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, filter

I'm trying to understand some built in method of array. Here is my code for small function, I want to display "name" and "category" of each item, which is store in inventory with total value larger than 1000. But when I try to print bigPrice, it always display all of property of each object and I only want to display "name" and "category". Anyone can help?

```
var products = [
{name: 'A', quantity: 2, unitPrice: 100, category: 'Electronic goods'},
{name: 'B', quantity: 1, unitPrice: 400, category: 'Electronic goods'},
{name: 'C', quantity: 5, unitPrice: 15, category: 'Clothing goods'},
{name: 'D', quantity: 2, unitPrice: 95, category: 'Clothing goods'},
{name: 'E', quantity: 300, unitPrice: 10, category: 'Home, Garden goods'},
{name: 'F', quantity: 60, unitPrice: 150, category: 'Handmade'},
{name: 'G', quantity: 10, unitPrice: 105, category: 'Automotive goods'}
];

var bigPrice = products.filter(function(item) {
if (item.quantity * item.unitPrice > 1000) {
    return item.name + ' || ' + item.category;
}
});

bigPrice;
```

Comment: Filter returns an array of the objects that match the criteria (i.e. the callback returns truth-y), not the result of the callback. See e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter.

Comment: `Array.filter()` expects that you return either true or false, depending on if the element has to stay or not. WHat you're trying to do here is either `Array.foEach()` or `Array.map()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

filter function doesn't return the custom value, you need to use `map and filter` together or alternatively `reduce`

```js
var products = [
{name: 'A', quantity: 2, unitPrice: 100, category: 'Electronic goods'},
{name: 'B', quantity: 1, unitPrice: 400, category: 'Electronic goods'},
{name: 'C', quantity: 5, unitPrice: 15, category: 'Clothing goods'},
{name: 'D', quantity: 2, unitPrice: 95, category: 'Clothing goods'},
{name: 'E', quantity: 300, unitPrice: 10, category: 'Home, Garden goods'},
{name: 'F', quantity: 60, unitPrice: 150, category: 'Handmade'},
{name: 'G', quantity: 10, unitPrice: 105, category: 'Automotive goods'}
];

var bigPrice = products.map(function(item) {
if (item.quantity * item.unitPrice > 1000) {
    return item.name + ' || ' + item.category;
}
}).filter(item => typeof item !== 'undefined');

console.log(bigPrice)
```

or

```js
var products = [
{name: 'A', quantity: 2, unitPrice: 100, category: 'Electronic goods'},
{name: 'B', quantity: 1, unitPrice: 400, category: 'Electronic goods'},
{name: 'C', quantity: 5, unitPrice: 15, category: 'Clothing goods'},
{name: 'D', quantity: 2, unitPrice: 95, category: 'Clothing goods'},
{name: 'E', quantity: 300, unitPrice: 10, category: 'Home, Garden goods'},
{name: 'F', quantity: 60, unitPrice: 150, category: 'Handmade'},
{name: 'G', quantity: 10, unitPrice: 105, category: 'Automotive goods'}
];

var bigPrice = products.filter(function(item) {
   return (item.quantity * item.unitPrice) > 1000
}).map(item => item.name + ' || ' + item.category);

console.log(bigPrice)
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I got it.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you return to the function passed to `filter` is only tested for truthyness, nothing else. If you return a (non-empty) string, it's determined to be truthy, and is then immediately discarded. For what you're doing, you could use `.filter` followed by `.map`, but it would be better to use `reduce` so you only have to iterate over the array once:

```js
var products = [
{name: 'A', quantity: 2, unitPrice: 100, category: 'Electronic goods'},
{name: 'B', quantity: 1, unitPrice: 400, category: 'Electronic goods'},
{name: 'C', quantity: 5, unitPrice: 15, category: 'Clothing goods'},
{name: 'D', quantity: 2, unitPrice: 95, category: 'Clothing goods'},
{name: 'E', quantity: 300, unitPrice: 10, category: 'Home, Garden goods'},
{name: 'F', quantity: 60, unitPrice: 150, category: 'Handmade'},
{name: 'G', quantity: 10, unitPrice: 105, category: 'Automotive goods'}
];

var bigPrice = products.reduce((a, { quantity, unitPrice, name, category }) => {
  if (quantity * unitPrice > 1000) a.push(name + ' || ' + category);
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(bigPrice);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` method and *destructing* by applying a provided *callback* function for every item from your given `array`.

```js
var products = [
{name: 'A', quantity: 2, unitPrice: 100, category: 'Electronic goods'},
{name: 'B', quantity: 1, unitPrice: 400, category: 'Electronic goods'},
{name: 'C', quantity: 5, unitPrice: 15, category: 'Clothing goods'},
{name: 'D', quantity: 2, unitPrice: 95, category: 'Clothing goods'},
{name: 'E', quantity: 300, unitPrice: 10, category: 'Home, Garden goods'},
{name: 'F', quantity: 60, unitPrice: 150, category: 'Handmade'},
{name: 'G', quantity: 10, unitPrice: 105, category: 'Automotive goods'}
];

var bigPrice = products.filter((item)=> item.quantity * item.unitPrice > 1000)
                       .map(({name,category})=>(name + '||' + category));

console.log(bigPrice);
```

Answer (score 0):

`filter` will create a new array with all the elements that return a truthy value from the function. You could use `filter` and then `map`:

```
var bigPrice = products.filter(function(item) {
  return item.quantity * item.unitPrice > 1000;
}).map(function(item) {
  return item.name + ' || ' + item.category;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array#reduce` for it because you need to filter and map at the same time:

```js
var products = [{
    name: 'A',
    quantity: 2,
    unitPrice: 100,
    category: 'Electronic goods'
  },
  {
    name: 'B',
    quantity: 1,
    unitPrice: 400,
    category: 'Electronic goods'
  },
  {
    name: 'C',
    quantity: 5,
    unitPrice: 15,
    category: 'Clothing goods'
  },
  {
    name: 'D',
    quantity: 2,
    unitPrice: 95,
    category: 'Clothing goods'
  },
  {
    name: 'E',
    quantity: 300,
    unitPrice: 10,
    category: 'Home, Garden goods'
  },
  {
    name: 'F',
    quantity: 60,
    unitPrice: 150,
    category: 'Handmade'
  },
  {
    name: 'G',
    quantity: 10,
    unitPrice: 105,
    category: 'Automotive goods'
  }
];

var bigPrice = products.reduce(function(res, item) {
  if (item.quantity * item.unitPrice > 1000) {
    res.push(item.name + ' || ' + item.category);
  }
  
  return res;
}, []);

console.log(bigPrice);
```

Comment: I also was downvoted but i wrote a correct answer. Thus, +1 for your correct answer also.

Answer (score 0):

You try to do two things at the same time.

- [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) returns an array of the same items, or not depending of the return value of the callback. Here, it is used to differentiate between smaller or greater prices.
- [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns for **every** item of the array a possible changed item, which is here a new streing instead of an object.

You could take a functional chanied approach by filtering first the wanted items of the array and the map the wanted properties.

This solution uses [destructuring <strike>assignment</strike>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for the properties.

```js
var products = [{ name: 'A', quantity: 2, unitPrice: 100, category: 'Electronic goods' }, { name: 'B', quantity: 1, unitPrice: 400, category: 'Electronic goods' }, { name: 'C', quantity: 5, unitPrice: 15, category: 'Clothing goods' }, { name: 'D', quantity: 2, unitPrice: 95, category: 'Clothing goods' }, { name: 'E', quantity: 300, unitPrice: 10, category: 'Home, Garden goods' }, { name: 'F', quantity: 60, unitPrice: 150, category: 'Handmade' }, { name: 'G', quantity: 10, unitPrice: 105, category: 'Automotive goods' }],
    big = products
        .filter(({ quantity, unitPrice }) => quantity * unitPrice > 1000)
        .map(({ name, category }) => [name, category].join(' || '));
        
console.log(big);
```